# Do something when a specified user react discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Hello i have a marry command and i want to do a reaction verify, when the tagged person reacts with ✅ do the actions i add there. I can't find a solution, tried already couple of times with different methods. I m a begginer with codding, thx.

this are the actions i want to do after nume2 message.mentions.members.first() reacts with the check.

```
message.member.roles.add(message.member.guild.roles.cache.get(config2.casatorit)) //add marry role to author
users.roles.add(message.member.guild.roles.cache.get(config2.casatorit)) //add marry role to @person
users.setNickname(`${nume2} + ${nume1}`) //set name to @person
message.member.setNickname(`${nume1} + ${nume2}`) //setname to author
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0):

If you can share your code maybe i could help you better but simpliest way to filter user in awaitReactions or createReactionCollector is;

```js
const filter = (emoji, user) => user.id === 'some user id';
```

```js
awaitReactions({filter, max: 1, time: 15000})
createReactionCollector({filter, max:1, time:15000})
```